# Array splicing vs reassigning to the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference, array-splice

I am solving a problem on leetcode that expects me to modify the array in place instead of creating a new one and then returning it. I thought of using `Array.prototype.splice` but ran into some issues. So I decided to use `Array.prototype.slice` and reassign the value to the existing array. Array being passed as a reference, I thought this would do the same thing as `.splice` method but that doesn't seem to happen.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on how these two things are giving different results. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const myMethod = (arr) => {
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      // my logic using arr.splice()
   }
}
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
myMethod(arr);
console.log(arr); // modified array
```

Other use case:

```
const myMethod = (arr) => {
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      // my logic using arr reassignment
     //  arr = arr.slice().....
   }
}
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
myMethod(arr);
console.log(arr); // outputs original array
```

Comment: A parameter to a function is like a local variable. Modifying it has absolutely no effect on whatever was passed in at the point of the function call.

Comment: @Pointy Hm. Thanks for bringing this up. How does `array.splice` work if that is the case?

Comment: In addition to what @Pointy wrote, If you change one of the values of the array, it will change outside of the function, but if you modify the variable arr, you simply replace its reference adn not changing the original array

Comment: @OmriAttiya Oh I see. Thank you. How could one then modify something in place without using `splice`?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question,

Comment: @Nur `Array.splice` update the array in-place. Hence the value of arr which is passed to the method will be get updated in the outer scope too. I am re-assigning the array value but when I do that it doesn't get updated in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use `filter()`. Then you don't even need to run a `for` loop. Filter returns an array of all elements that match the given condition.

```
const myMethod = (arr) =>  {
     return arr.filter(entry => {
            // filter by whatever condition you like
            // example: entry > 2 && < 10
     }  
 }
```

Comment: I want to update the array in place so that if I try to log the array outside the method, after calling the method on that array, I should be able to see the updated results.